# ArrayList <ArrayList <Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist

Как правильно добавлять элементы к списку типа

`ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>`?

Я делаю так:

```
ArrayList <Integer> gf=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <ArrayList <Integer>> gg=new ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>();

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  gf.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    rg = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    gf.add(rg);
  }
  System.out.println(gg);
  gg.add(gf);
}
```

Ожидаю

```
(0,0)
(0,0)(1,0)
(0,0)(1,0)(0,1)
```

Получается

```
(0,0)
(1,0)(1,0)
(0,1)(0,1)(0,1)
```

?

Comment: Вы код сюда руками переписали? Видимо, опечатка -- компилятор не должен принимать переменную `i` во внутреннем цикле. И этот код, который вы привели, выводит пустой список в первой строке, список с одним списком во второй, и список с двумя списками в третьей. Чего  вы хотели добиться, непонятно.

Comment: Да опечатка. В первом цикле другая переменная. Исправил

Comment: А в чем разница между тем, что хотите получить, и тем, что получаете? Если вы имеете в виду конкретные числа, то они каждый раз разные, потому что `random`, а других различий я не вижу. И как я сказал, выдача, которую вы привели, не соответствует коду -- ваш код выводит `[]
[[0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код добавляет в `gg` один и тот же список `ArrayList <Integer>`.

---

```
ArrayList <ArrayList <Integer>> gg = new ArrayList<ArrayList <Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ArrayList <Integer> gf = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    ...
  }
  gg.add(gf);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это решило проблему. Непонятно, почему с clear(); не прошло.

Comment: Если вы в качестве элементов первого списка добавляете три раза один и тот же список, это и будет один и тот же список, независимо от того, что вы с ним делаете в промежутках. Если при втором и третьем проходе вы его очистили что-то добавили, то вы тем самым очистили первый список и добавили в него. После окончания вашего фрагмента, если вы распечатаете список, то увидите три одинаковых строки. Это просто в первом списке (`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`)  у вас лежат три ссылки на один и тот же единственный список `ArrayList<Integer>` с числами.